# Is there anything python function decorators can do that I can't do with first class functions?

Tags: python, python-decorators, first-class-functions

I'm trying to understand Python function decorators, but so far I don't see any case where a function decorator can do something I couldn't do using first class functions.

As an example, the `logger decorator` is often given as a simple example of a useful function decorator:

```
def logger(f):
    def new_f():
        print("Calling %s" % f.__name__)
        return f()
return new_f
```

This decorator is then classically used together with a function we want to log, as so:

```
@logger
def fun1():
    [do something]
```

However, for the same result we could just define func1 and wrap it with logger:

```
def fun2():
    [do something]
def logged_fun2():
    return logger(fun2)()
```

Calling `logged_fun2` is analogue to calling `fun1`. In addition, when we wrap `fun2` with `logger` we can still call the original `fun2` without logging if we wish to.

Are there things I can do with decorators that I can't do using first class functions? Or is it better to look at decorators as a form of syntactic sugar for wrapping functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorator syntax:

```
@deco
def f(...):
    ...
```

is [defined](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) as exactly equivalent to the following syntax:

```
def f(...):
    ...
f = deco(f)
```

So no, there's nothing decorators can do that first-class functions can't. Decorators *are* first-class functions.

Comment: "Decorators are first-class functions." Correct, from my expert knowledge of Python decorators and my brief review of "first class functions"